# Unit test to confirm that `def __init__()` runs

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, init

I have a class with two methods and I want to add a unit test that confirms that my `__init__` method is run.

```
class MyClass(graphene.ObjectType, SomeOtherClass):
    def func(self):
        ...

    def __init__(self, args, context, info):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
```

How can I test that the **init** function runs? That's really the only thing I would need to test in this case.

I've looked at documentation, but nothing I've seen has helped me implement a test that checks that `__init__` runs... Any help would be appreciated.